# How to get GitLab project name by using Project id in GitLab API

Tags: api, gitlab

I have a script which prints project id with other attributes like allowed to push , allowed to merge I need to replace project name with project id. How is this possible?

```
PROJECT=$(cat /var/opt/gitlab/.project)
TOKEN=$(cat /var/opt/gitlab/.token)
URL=$(cat /etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb | grep external_url | grep -vE 'pages|registry' | grep -v ^# | cut -f 2 -d "'")
projectId=( $(curl -sS --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: $TOKEN" "$URL/api/v4/projects?&per_page=100&sort=asc&page=[1-50]"| jq -r .[].id) )
for i in "${projectId[@]}"
do
branch1=( $( curl -sS --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: $TOKEN" "$URL/api/v4/projects/$i/protected_branches" | jq -r ".[]" | jq -r ".name") )
        branch1=( $( curl -sS --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: $TOKEN" "$URL/api/v4/projects/$i/protected_branches" | jq ".path_with_namespace") )
        for  branch in "${branch1[@]}"
        do
        Allowed_to_push=( $(curl -sS --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: $TOKEN" "$URL/api/v4/projects/$i/protected_branches/"$branch""| jq -r .push_access_levels |grep -o '"access_level_description": *"[^"]*"' | grep -o '"[^"]*"$') )
        Allowed_to_Merge=( $(curl -sS --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: $TOKEN" "$URL/api/v4/projects/$i/protected_branches/"$branch""| jq -r .merge_access_levels |grep -o '"access_level_description": *"[^"]*"' | grep -o '"[^"]*"$') )
        Allow_to_force_push=( $(curl -sS --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: $TOKEN" "$URL/api/v4/projects/$i/protected_branches/"$branch""| jq -r .allow_force_push) )
echo  -e "$branch,\t\t\t\t$i,\t\t\t\t$Allowed_to_push,\t\t\t\t$Allowed_to_Merge,\t\t\t\t$Allow_to_force_push" >> input.json
        done
echo -e "Branch,\t\t\t\tprojectname,\t\t\t\tAllowed_to_push,\t\t\t\tAllowed_to_Merge,\t\t\t\tAllow_to_force_push" | cat - input.json > output.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

Easier using the [`python-gitlab` wrapper](https://python-gitlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/).

`python3 -m pip install python-gitlab`

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import gitlab

gl = gitlab.Gitlab('https://gitlab.com', private_token='your API token')

# Replace with your project path
PROJECT_NAME = 'mynamespace/myproject'

project = gl.projects.get(PROJECT_NAME)

print('PROJECT:', project.path_with_namespace)
print('PROJECT ID:', project.id)

protected_branches = project.protectedbranches.list(all=True)

print('PROTECTED BRANCHES:')
for branch in protected_branches:
    print(f'{branch.name}:')
    print('  allowed to merge:')
    for grant in branch.merge_access_levels:
        print('   ', grant['access_level_description'] or grant['user_id'] or grant['group_id'])
    print('  allowed to push:')
    for grant in branch.push_access_levels:
        print('   ', grant['access_level_description'] or grant['user_id'] or grant['group_id'])
    print('  force push allowed?')
    print('   ', branch.allow_force_push)
```

Output will show something like:

```
PROJECT: mynamespace/myproject
PROJECT ID: 1234
PROTECTED BRANCHES:
master:
  allowed to merge:
    Maintainers
  allowed to push:
    No one
  force push allowed?
    False
```

If you really wish to not use the python-gitlab API, the relevant APIs you need are:

1. The [projects API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/projects.html)
2. The [protected branches API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/protected_branches.html)

Comment: We don't use python gitlab. Can you please help in fixing the API script?

Answer (score 0):

You already have the list of project IDs and you're doing some magic with them. You could easily add the following to your `for` loop to get the project name. Please note that you could also get `name_with_namespace` API reference which might also be useful. You could always check out the [GitLab project documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/projects.html) to see what you can get from the API.

```
projectId=( $(curl -sS --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: $TOKEN" "$URL/api/v4/projects?&per_page=100&sort=asc&page=[1-50]"| jq -r .[].id) )
for i in "${projectId[@]}"
do
  projectName=$(curl -sS --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: $TOKEN" "$URL/api/v4/projects/${i} | jq '.name')
  echo $projectName
done
```